# Dynamically create and set members/properties of class at runtime

Tags: c#, class, oop, dynamic

How can I create and set members/properties of a class dynamically at runtime.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember(v=vs.110).aspx

I tried to modify the idea to suit my requirements but unable to do it.

I am required to set the class members at runtime, means I would fetch the `Key` and `Value` from the database and my class will be completely dynamic with no members defined before runtime, but all of them is fetched from database during runtime.

So here goes my code (Taken from MSDN):

```
public class DynamicObjDictionary : DynamicObject
{
    // The inner dictionary.
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public int Count
    {
        get{return dictionary.Count;}
    }

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();
        return dynDict.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dynDict[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
        return true;
    }
 }
}
```

The code that initializes and defines the members/properties of the class

```
dynamic DynObj = new DynamicObjDictionary();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetObjectProperties() // returns dataset having the properties as key and value pair;
        if (ds.Tables["PropTable"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["PropTable"].Rows)
            {
                string KeyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString();
                string ValueName= dr["ValueName"].ToString();
                //---I want that in place of fldName the actual value from dr is added to the class - currently it returns DynObj.KeyName only.
                DynObj.KeyName = ValueName;
                // Means if current dr["KeyName"].ToString() has "Property1"
                // And dr["ValueName"].ToString() has "PropertyValue"
                // The DynObj should be like DynObj.Property1 = "PropertyValue" 
            }
        }
```

And another problem is that I want all the properties to be set after the above initialization so that I can access them like a class object that is hard-coded. Current code only retails the last property i.e. the value of the last row of the dataset.

Comment: Why don't you use an ExpandoObject ?

Comment: If you do it like this, how will you access these properties later on? You would then need to know the *KeyName*, but if you already know it, why don't you just use a dictionary?

Comment: All of your values will be strings?

Comment: @DanielHäfele, the class would be serializable and will be use to return json for webservice so, the knowing `KeyName` is not a matter of concern.

Comment: @Cyberpks why not just use a naked dictionary then? most json serializers know exactly what you mean if you pass them a dictionary...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either add a dictionary-based API, or use an implementation that already has it. Frankly `ExpandoObject` would work fine, and has an `IDictionary<string,object>` API built in.

```
var obj = new ExpandoObject();
DataSet ds = GetObjectProperties() // returns dataset having the properties as key and value pair;
if (ds.Tables["PropTable"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["PropTable"].Rows)
    {
        string KeyName = dr["KeyName"].ToString();
        string ValueName= dr["ValueName"].ToString();
        obj[KeyName] = ValueName;
    }
}
dynamic DynObj = obj;
// ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and the suggestion above. I had to actually use an `ExpandoObject()` so as to maintain that `Key-Value` pair, and then return the data as dynamic.

Comment: @marc: i tried your code but this line is giving error obj[KeyName] = ValueName; i am using VS2010. any help.

Comment: @Thomas ah, it is entirely possible I wrote that on a 'phone! You might need to cast `obj` to `IDictionary<string,object>` to access the indexer

Comment: Yep.  Definitely had to cast the ExpandoObject:
((IDictionary<string, object>)obj)[KeyName] = ValueName;